# Set Falang default language for joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I have my site in English & Spanish. I am using Falang Extension in Joomla and need to make Spanish language default. So that when a user visit the site he/she will see the Spanish language.

Is there anything I can do to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can install additional languages and choose your default from the Joomla Administrators Language Manager.  Details at the [Extensions Help](http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&view=help&keyref=Help16%3aExtensions_Extension_Manager_Install).  If your language isn't available from joomla.org directly, or you need additional language support, check the [JED Language Support](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/translations-for-joomla).

Comment: I try changing the default language in joomla administrator, but it deosnt help me---no change!!- its always english even if I select spanish as default language

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to **Language Filter plugin** configuration.

You have to open:

```
Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> System - Language Filter
```

And set:

```
Language Selection for new Visitors: Site Language
```

Hope this helps